# does not disconnecting HttpUrlConnection implies a resource lack or a network lag

Tags: java, networking, connection, httpurlconnection

When dealing with `HttpUrlConnection` in JAVA, are we obliged (or is it recommended) to disconnect each connection we create ? and if we do not close connections, does this implies a network saturation?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: According [to this blog entry](https://techblog.bozho.net/caveats-of-httpurlconnection/), usage of `disconnect()` is not needed because the TCP connection pool will auto-close the connection after some idle time. If you disconnect the `HttpUrlConnection`, the underlying TCP socket will get closed further reusage of this socket will be prevented. So, if you are going to send multiple requests to the other host, it would actually be better not to call `disconnect()`.

Comment: Thank you, and I want to know if disconnecting an HttpUrlConnection implies a request to be sent to the same host?

Comment: Yes, the socket gets shut down which is signalled to the other end.

Comment: So if the internet connection is slow or the server has some problems, the .disconnect() method would take some time to execute? !

Comment: This is hard to tell. It may or may not depend on your used communication protocol (HTTP/HTTPS), transport protocol (TCP/UDP) and `HttpUrlConnection` implementation. For an overview of connection close scenarios, view [HTTP: The definitive guide on shutdowns](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s07.html)
If I may implore, why do you use this old class? I would much more recommend `ApacheHttpClient`.

Comment: Please note my edit to my answer which was wrong. It is not necessary to disconnect the HttpUrlConnection.

Answer (score 1):

It's more about memory leaking and resource wasting.
Hence yes it is highly recommended to explicitly close your connection once used, e.g. in a finally clause.